# Auto expanding Container in flutter -- for all devices

Tags: flutter, containers, expand

I need a Container with some text in to auto expand. I have an API call, which can be anything from 5 words to 500 words. I don't want to just have 1 fixed size that's huge, but contains 10 words.

I have tried Expanded() and SizedBox.Expand(), but I might be using them wrong

```
Card( 
 elevation: defaultTargetPlatform ==
      TargetPlatform.android ? 5.0 : 0.0,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
        width: _screenSize.width,
        height: 250,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: _screenSize.width,
              height: 35,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15, top: 11),
                child: Text("Title".toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: _screenSize.width,
              height: 210,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 5),
                    child: Text("Title of expanding text", style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Expanding text", style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800
                  ),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I just need the Container to expand, but stay small/get bigger

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you tried not specifying `height` at all? The `Container` should wrap according to the child in this case.

> Otherwise, the widget has a child but no height, no width, no
>   constraints, and no alignment, and the Container passes the
>   constraints from the parent to the child and sizes itself to match the
>   child.

Above is an extract from the official flutter documentation for `Container`.

Here is the official flutter documentation [link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html).

Comment: Thanks this solved it. I just added some padding as well, so that it doesn't touch the bottom of the Container

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!

Comment: What about when a child is a listview?

Comment: The above method will throw an error for `ListView` since `ListView` always tends to wrap itself within the bounds of the parent widget.

Comment: This does NOT work with a GridView or ListView

Comment: Container can't auto height a unknown height Listview child.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`FittedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html), this will resize your text according to available area.

You can use it like this :

```
FittedBox(child: Text('...............Your text...............'));
```

Comment: This will also decrease the `fontSize` automatically.

Comment: You can use: FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.none) @CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest you to use Constraints...this will set Container height according to the Text child's requirement. Please see the example...

```dart
Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: double.infinity,
),
child: Column(
children: [
  Text(
    'Hello flutter...i like flutter...i like google...',
    softWrap: true,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20 , ),

  ),],),)
```

Answer (score 10):

we just neeed to add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` properties inside child  `Column` or `Row` where the child is set to `Container`

for example

```dart
AnythingYourWidget(
  child: Container(
    child: Column( // For Example Column
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // these properties following the children content height available.
      children: [
          // YourWidget
      ]
    )
  )
),
```

Answer (score 4):

I too had a container with a text widget inside that would not scale as the text increased in character count.  Make the widget tree Container -> IntrinsicWidth -> Text/TextField and it seems to play nicely for me.

IntrinsicWidth will scale the size of the container to its child.