# Flutter: How to fit TextField inside row and container

Tags: flutter

how to fit TextFiled inside row > container. i don't why TextField it goes beyond the container and also the height of the textField is not properly adjected. can anyone help...

```
 child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.verified_user_outlined),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 30,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter Your Mobile Number',
                          errorText: '',
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: () => {}, child: Text("Continue")),
          ],[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's because that you hard coded your container's width and height. try not setting the width and height of the container which will dynamically change the container's width and height depending on it's child. for more information you can visit here [dynamic container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609811/auto-expanding-container-in-flutter-for-all-devices)

Answer (score 0):

try using Expanded widget and flex on children

```
child: Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Icon(Icons.verified_user_outlined)),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: SizedBox(width: 5)),
    Expanded(
      flex: 4,
      child: Container(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use SizedBox widget to your textfiled
Or use Expand widget with flex property
```

Eg:

```
SizedBox(
width:20.0,
heigh : 30.0,
child: //text field 
),

Expanded(
flex:1,
child: //text field 
),
```